# Raspberry Pi car connection to laptop in the park where there is no internet

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have built a small Raspberry Pi 4 car which can be controlled via my laptop. Both Raspberry Pi and Laptop are connected to my home internet. I want to take the car outside in the park. There is no internet outside in the park. So how will my Raspberry Pi receive commands from my laptop when there is no internet connection? I do not want to use hotspotting from my mobile. I have seen videos where people are using their Raspberry Pi cars outside without any internet, but I do not know how they are doing it. I will appreciate some help. Thank you

Comment: `Both Raspberry Pi and Laptop are connected to my home internet` .... that is not entirely true ... they are connected to your LAN, not to internet ... the internet connection is irrelevant ...

Answer (score 1):

Your Raspberry Pi has a quite capable WiFi. You can configure it to be a hotspot (access point). When it is operating in that mode, you can connect your laptop, phone, or other devices, to its network. Bear in mind, though, that tiny network is not connected to the Internet.

Do an internet search for "Raspberry Pi wifi hotspot" to find out the config details. Retain the previous config settings somehow, though, so you can restore them to be able to reconnect the Pi to your home net.

Answer (score 1):

Two [LoRa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LoRa) modules (one for the laptop and one for the pi) should work well to control your Raspberry Pi from your laptop over a long distance, where there is no WiFi available.

Another option could be Bluetooth, but you would be limited by range.